# App Will Not Be Terminated After backgroundTimeRemaining Reached Zero

Tags: swift, background, uiapplication

I used below code to determine how many time remained to suspending my app. First I called `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask` but after `backgroundTimeRemaining`reached zero my app was not terminated.
In another scenario I didn't call `UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask` but again my app has 180 seconds to run in background and after `backgroundTimeRemaining` reached zero, my app was not terminated again.

So can it be said that there is no force to call `beginBackgroundTask` to get more time? Or it depends on system situation?

My main question is why system didn't terminate my app after `backgroundTimeRemaining` reached zero, while I didn't call `endBackgroundTask`?

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let app = UIApplication.shared
        while app.backgroundTimeRemaining > 0 {
                print(app.backgroundTimeRemaining, " seconds to suspend.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running your app from Xcode? App's are not terminated when you run through Xcode.

Comment: Yes I'm running from Xcode. I didn't know. Thanks.
Is there any way that I force Xcode to run app in real situation?